# SQS triggers Lambda with multiple records/messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've observed an abnormal (well, in my POV) feature, where when I setup SQS to trigger a Lambda, when new messages arrive, lambdas get triggered with more than 1 record/message inside its event body.

Full setup is S3 (PutObjectEvent) -> SNS topic -> SQS -> Lambda.

The abnormal behaviour is that for example, let's say I put 15 objects inside S3, which then forwards an event to SNS per each object, which then I can observe, SQS gets populated with 15 messages.  However, when Lambdas start triggering, out of those 15 messages, only 11 Lambdas trigger, some of them containing more than 1 record/message inside its event body.

I've scoured the AWS documentation, but haven't found a concrete answer. Please note, these Lambdas do NOT poll SQS or fail or keep retrying. They execute perfectly fine, its just that inspected event body shows more than 1 record inside of it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Look at the sample event data for an SQS Lambda message [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sqs). The message is an array of records, which directly implies that there may be more than one SQS record in the message.

[The documentation on SQS Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) also clearly states that the `Batch Size` setting controls how many records a Lambda function may receive from SQS in a single call, with the default being `10`. If you only want your Lambda functions to receive one message at a time you need to modify the `Batch Size` setting to be `1`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was wondering about the batch size and record amount.